# How can I decrease the width of the columns when there are only 2 data points

Tags: charts, chart.js, bar-chart

As you can see from the following image, there are only 2 data points with the whole graph is stretching to full screen, instead I want the graph to take full width but I want to control the widths of the columns.

[image: Bar Graph]

I have only 2 data points coming from API and it's stretching the graph.

The data used from Examples provided

```js
const labels = Utils.months({count: 2});
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
      'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)',
      'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
      'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
      'rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
      'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
      'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
      'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
      'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
      'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
      'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
    ],
    borderWidth: 1,
    categoryPercentage: 1.0,
    barPercentage:1.0,
    
  }]
};
```